# How to achieve pivot output in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot-table

Source is as following :

```
NAME |SEX
-----+----
A    |MALE
B    |FEMALE
C    |MALE
D    |FEMALE
E    |MALE
```

Required output, pivoting the values in the second column as the headings, as following :

```
MALE FEMALE
A     B
C     D
E
```

Comment: This question shows a total lack of effort and research on your part.

Comment: Will you be able to elaborate?

Comment: So if you have 3 males in your source and 2 females, would you want in your output to have 3 data items in the MALE column and 2 data items in the FEMALE column?

Comment: @MarkStewart  yes if i will have 3 males then it should show 3 males in males column and null in female column

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle:

```
select * from (
select * from [table name]
)src 
pivot
(max(name) for sex in ('Male' as MALE,'Female' as FEMALE))pvt
```

For SQL Server:

```
select * from (
select * from [table name]
)src 
pivot
(max(name) for sex in ([Male],[Female]))pvt
```

Comment: Already tried it through pivot but it is returning last set of data Male - C Female D  --- select * from src pivot (max(name) for sex in ('MALE','FEMALE'));